# Mac OS X 10.10 disable USB ports

Tags: macos, usb

Can anyone tell me how to disable all usb-ports on OSX 10.10 (Yosemite)?
We've got a large number of iMacs setup, where we don't want the user to be able to control/use USB ports.

In previous OSX versions, the command was

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions
mv IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext/ IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext.bup
```

But this no longer works under Yosemite?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so I'd suggest that you try asking over on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually found a solution, i now use

```
cd /System/Library/Extensions/
sudo kextunload IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext
```

and after that all usbs are disabled.

Comment: How do you reenable them, if needed?

Comment: Sorry for another comment, but does this work on 10.10.4?